# How to get back parentheses and commas from pyparsing select_parser.py?

Tags: pyparsing

Below is an example of some pyparsing code that takes a SQL statement, and prints it again, but without parentheses and commas, using the [select_parser.py example](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/select_parser.py).  What is the easiest way to get them back?

I thought it dropped commas and parentheses because they were defined as follows:

```
LPAR,RPAR,COMMA = map(Suppress,"(),")
```

So I modified them to be defined as symbols:

```
LPAR='('
RPAR=')'
COMMA=','
```

Then I thought it was because there are delimitedList elements that drop the commas.  So, I named every delimited list, and re-inserted the commas if the ParseResult has one of the names.  (Is there an easier way to detect if a ParseResult is a delimited list?  Or more generally, which element it is?  I see [getName()](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParseResults-class.html#getName), but what about unnamed elements?)

**Edit**: [This example](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~shipman/soft/pyparsing/web/delimitedList.html) shows fusing a delimited list with ', '.  Although then I have to change every example in the grammar, and it feels weird to change the grammar for the formatting.  Ideally, I could have something say, "for every delimited list, put back the commas."

But what is suppressing the parentheses?

P.S. I want to output all of it because I'm on my way to a SQL formatter, if all goes well.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from select_parser import select_stmt
from pyparsing import ParseResults

def struct_to_list(struct):
    elems = []
    for elem in struct:
        if isinstance(elem, ParseResults):
            elems.extend(struct_to_list(elem))
        else:
            elems.append(elem)
    return elems


stmt = "select (1 and 2) or 3 as one, 4 as two from b"
print struct_to_list(select_stmt.parseString(stmt))

select_stmt.runTests(stmt)
```

Output:

```
['SELECT', '1', 'AND', '2', 'OR', '3', 'AS', 'one', '4', 'AS', 'two', 'FROM', 'b']

select (1 and 2) or 3 as one, 4 as two from b
['SELECT', [[[['1', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', '3'], 'AS', 'one'], ['4', 'AS', 'two']], 'FROM', 'b']
- columns: [[[['1', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', '3'], 'AS', 'one'], ['4', 'AS', 'two']]
  [0]:
    [[['1', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', '3'], 'AS', 'one']
    [0]:
      [['1', 'AND', '2'], 'OR', '3']
      [0]:
        ['1', 'AND', '2']
      [1]:
        OR
      [2]:
        3
    [1]:
      AS
    [2]:
      one
  [1]:
    ['4', 'AS', 'two']
- from: ['b']
- table: [['b']]
  [0]:
    ['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recapture the original pre-parse text using `originalTextFor`. Here is a simple example using `delimitedList`, which you observed removes the delimiters and just returns the parsed list items:

```
source = "1,2,3, 4,5"

import pyparsing as pp
expr = pp.delimitedList(pp.pyparsing_common.integer)
print(expr.parseString(source))
```

Gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

(Note that `pyparsing_common.integer` has an attached parse action that converts the string values to ints, so these are integers 1, 2, 3, not string "1", "2", "3", etc.)

If you wrap that expression with `originalTextFor`, then you will get back the original parsed text, even if there is embedded whitespace that was skipped during parsing:

```
print(pp.originalTextFor(expr).parseString(source))
```

Gives:

```
['1,2,3, 4,5']
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I don't exactly want to recover the pre-parsed text. Since I'm making a pretty-printer, I want pretty standardized text. Rather, I want to prevent the parser from dropping any tokens (commas or parens). I want to be able to reform "select (1 and 2) or 3 as one, 4 as two from b" with parens and commas, but I'll probably put one field per line, capitalize all the keywords (which happens automatically), etc.